# cookie sets new value after twice click on link or refresh page Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a multi lang site and I must save selected lang from menu in a Cookie for use in other pages but my problem is this works after twice click on lang link I use middleware for that and The codes have come following:

middleware:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->lang){
            Cookie::queue('lang',$request->lang);
        }else{
            Cookie::queue('lang','fa');
        }

        $lang=$request->lang ? $request->lang : "fa";
        app()->setLocale($lang);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>[\App\Http\Middleware\SetDefaultLocaleForUrls::class]],function (){
    Route::get('/{lang?}','Welcomecontroller@index')->name('lang');
    Route::get('/{lang?}/text','Welcomecontroller@text')->name('text');
});
```

links in blade file :

```
  <a href="{{route('lang',['en'])}}">en</a>
    <a href="{{route('lang',['ru'])}}">ru</a>
    <a href="{{route('lang')}}">fa</a>
    <a href="{{route('text',[Cookie::get('lang')])}}">text Page</a>
```

when I click on link first the cookie value is the past value and when I click again cookie value changes to new where is my code problem?

Comment: Did u solve this? I have same issue